# NameError no get_special_folder_path

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

Fiz um pequeno teste em Python 2.X para tentar copiar um arquivo da pasta que o script está para a pasta de inicialização do Windows:

```
import shutil
import sys, os

startuplocation = get_special_folder_path("CSIDL_STARTUP")
shutil.copy('fototest.jpg', startuplocation)
```

no entanto, recebo a mensagem:

> File "copytest.py", line 5, in 
>       startuplocation = get_special_folder_path("CSIDL_STARTUP") NameError: name 'get_special_folder_path' is not defined.

Comecei a usar o Python a pouco tempo e não entendo o que há de errado.

Comment: O método `get_special_folder_path` pertence a qual classe? Ai esta dizendo que ele não esta definido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caro amigo Pythonista, muito obrigado pela preferência de linguagem hehehe! Este script que você está fazendo seria para um pós-instalador?

Caso contrário, a função get_special_folder_path(csidl_string) não funcionará!
Se você ainda quer encontrar o local de StartUp de seu computador, utilize este script(caso seja Windows):

```
import winshell
startup = winshell.startup()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, não sabia que só funcionava no pós-instalador. A solução apresentada solucionou o meu problema.

Comment: Opa se você precisar de ajuda, só chamar!